# How do I properly include files from the NVIDIA C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, visual-studio-2019, std

I was trying to use shared pointers in CUDA by using NVIDIA's [version](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/) of the C++ standard library. So tried to include `<cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/memory>`. I got some errors. One of them includes `cannot open source file` with `<__config>` and `<__functional_base>`. Those files were clearly in the directory. It's like visual studios acts like those files don't exist even though they do. Another error I get is `linkage specification is incompatible with previous ""` with `<cmath>`.

I did little digging. I found out that `cannot open source file` is apparent with every non-header file that starts with _ in `cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/`. It is like Visual Studio somehow acts like those files don't exist despite being clearly located in the additional include directories. Furthermore, when I type `cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/`, IntelliSense won't find these files. If I can get visual studio to recognize those files, I can properly include any files in NVIDIA's version of standard library.

Comment: Cuda has its own version of the standard library. It's called libcu++.  I even pointed to the directory of those files in the standard library,  ```cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include/```.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to understand is that CUDA doesn't have a C++ standard library. What you are referring to is the libcu++, which is an *extremely* bare bones heterogenous reimplementation of a tiny subset of what is defined in the C++ standard library. You can use whatever is defined in libcu++ (and that is not much, it is a very incomplete implementation) as follows:

1. Prepend the local path `cuda/std/` to whatever standard library header you are using to substitute the import from the native host C++ standard library to `libcu++`
2. Change the namespace from `std` to `cuda::std`
3. compile using `nvcc`

As a simple [example](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/atomic/):

```
$ cat atomics.cpp

#include <iostream>         // std::cout
#include <cuda/std/atomic>  // cuda::std::atomic, cuda::std::atomic_flag, ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT
#include <thread>           // std::thread, std::this_thread::yield
#include <vector>           // std::vector

cuda::std::atomic<bool> ready (false);
cuda::std::atomic_flag winner = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

void count1m (int id) {
  while (!ready) { std::this_thread::yield(); }      // wait for the ready signal
  for (volatile int i=0; i<1000000; ++i) {}          // go!, count to 1 million
  if (!winner.test_and_set()) { std::cout << "thread #" << id << " won!\n"; }
};

int main ()
{
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  std::cout << "spawning 10 threads that count to 1 million...\n";
  for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i) threads.push_back(std::thread(count1m,i));
  ready = true;
  for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -std=c++11 -o atomics atomics.cpp -lpthread
$ ./atomics
spawning 10 threads that count to 1 million...
thread #6 won!
```

Note that as per the [documentation](https://nvidia.github.io/libcudacxx/standard_api.html), there are presently (CUDA 11.2) only implementations of:

- `<atomic>`
- `<latch>`
- `<barrier>`
- `<semaphore>`
- `<chrono>`
- `<cfloat>`
- `<ratio>`
- `<climits>`
- `<cstdint>`
- `<type_traits>`
- `<tuple>`
- `<functional>`
- `<utility>`
- `<version>`
- `<cassert>`
- `<cstddef>`

with complex support coming in the next CUDA release from the looks of things.

You mentioned shared pointers. There is no `<memory>` implementation at present, so that cannot be made to work.

Comment: So the files in `cuda/std/detail/libcxx/include` directory don't count as implementations. `<memory>` is in that directory.

Comment: You can't (or shouldn't) directly import anything in `std/detail` in *any* libC++ implementation. Just because there are files there, doesn't mean that they can be used directly or contain anything that is meaningful. They are *internal implementation details* which are deliberately hidden from view. The top level headers are always the entry point the API.

Comment: Thrust pointers are not the same in form and function as the smart pointers declared in `<memory>`  in the C++ standard library. There is no reference counting/garbage collection, etc. The are really only a device to make tag based algorithm selection possible within the library itself